# fprintf an unsigned long as a char

Tags: c, printf, long-integer

I want to do something like:

```
unsigned long addr = 0x000decaf;
...
fprintf(fp, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$s", addr);
```

Normally I would do

```
unsigned long addr = 0x000decaf;
memcpy(buf, &addr, 4);
```

But since my program uses getLine() on an input file so having something like `AAAA\x00\x01BBBB` will get treated as `'A','A','A','A','\','x','0','0',...` what are some of the tricks I can do to make getLine() to do the equivalence of what I am trying to do with memcpy()

Comment: What precise output do you expect?

Comment: Im memory, I want something like 0x41414141 0x000decaf 0x42424242

Comment: The title is "fprintf  ..." implies a question about output.  Post asks "what are some of the tricks I can do to make `getLine()`  ..." implies a question about input.  Recommend re-writing the post to fix this contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `%lu` token to print an `unsigned long`:

```
fprintf(fp, "%lu", addr);
```

If you want it in hex:

```
fprintf(fp, "0x%x", addr);
```

Comment: `%lx` instead of `%x`

Comment: fprintf() write is as AAAAA13200BBBB, so when getLine() reads it it will create a char array as ['A','A','A','A','A','1','3','2','0','0','B','...], instead of AAAA[whatever 0xdeadbeef is represented as]BBBBB.

Comment: I want something in memory like

0x41414141 0xdeadbeef 0x42424242

and not

0x41414141 0x010300200 0x4242424242